# how can I say ''I post about Japanese history, mythology and culture'' properly?

Tags: grammar, sentence

I have been learning Japanese for almost a year. However, I still have some hardship on writing something in Japanese...

Would it be okay If I put it like this:

> 日本の歴史{れきし}、文化{ぶんか}と神話{しんわ}について投稿{とうこう}する。

It doesn't really make sense to me but I can't seem to organize it properly.. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 5):

> 「日本{にほん}の歴史{れきし},文化{ぶんか}と神話{しんわ}について投稿{とうこう}する.」

This is a nice try and virtually all Japanese-speakers would understand what you are trying to say.

If I were asked, however, whether or not that sentence was 100% natural-sounding, I would have to say 'no'.

It would be more natural if you used the verb form 「投稿**しています**」 if you have already been doing it even for a couple of days.  This is indeed one of the biggest differences between real Japanese and Japanese-as-a-foreign-language.

I have seen/heard *so many* Japanese-learners say:

「わたしは大学{だいがく}で日本語{にほんご}を勉強{べんきょう}**します**。」

Native Japanese speakers, however, would invariably say:

「（わたしは）大学で英語{えいご}を勉強**しています**。」

The first sentence using 「します」 is grammatical, but it can sound like studying Japanese is something the speaker plans to do in the (near) future.  It sounds like something said by a high school senior who is planning to study or major in Japanese in college.

Next, the 「日本の歴史,文化と神話について」 part is not necessarily incorrect or unnatural, but it can be improved a little.  I would recommend:

・「日本の歴史、文化そして神話**など**について」

・「日本の歴史や文化、更{さら}に神話などについて」

Comment: Thank you so much, I am trying as hard as I can in order to sound natural.

Answer (score -1):

歴​史と文​化と神​話 - there is no enumeration comma.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but even with the changes you listed, I think the sentence will still sound unnatural.

Comment: @ajsmart But nonetheless, you would agree that the comma is an error, I assume. Probably better: 歴​史と文​化と神​話について口コミを投稿する

Comment: I agree that the comma was an error.  The issue in my opinion is the 'to post' part.  I personally am not sure what sounds natural in that situation, but I can say that what was originally posted seemed off to me.